# Difference between these two relations

Tags: postgresql

pretty much noob here. What is the difference between these two schema for shopping website.

Normally I use this schema.

[image]

I saw this one here (https://github.com/ramortegui/e-commerce-db)

[image]

Should I keep using the first one or change to second. Is there any advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In example 1 every product can have only one category.
Example 2 allows multiple categories per product.

Answer (score 1):

To provide you better understanding,

[image]